# MySQL Query to select 5 records from a join in a sub-query

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

Kind people of Stackoverflow, I am currently struggling with a small part of my latest project.

Currently working with an image gallery.

For simplicity, I have two tables:

```
**albums**
album_id, album_title


**media**
media_id, album_id, media_title
```

I need to display a list of 5 albums and for each album up to 5 items of media in that album.

So I want my query to select 5 albums, and then up to 5 media items that have the same album_id

I want to perform this with the minimum number of queries possible, and also the best performance as possible (so I have this working already by just getting all albums, getting all media and then looping through them, but that isn't scalable if some albums contain hundreds of media items).

I always appreciate the fantastic help I get here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the media in a comma delimited list by using `group_concat()`:

```
select a.*,
       substring_index(group_concat(distinct m.media_title), ',', 5)
from albums a join
     media m
     on a.album_id = m.album_id
group by a.album_id
limit 5;
```

Comment: Oh nice. I hadn't thought of doing it like that. I deliberately simplified my OP table structure. The media table joins on to other tables and has many more fields so ultimately it would be more useful to have the media records as an associative array in PHP rather than comma delimited. But that's a great solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

By way of example...

```
CREATE TABLE colours(colour_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,colour VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO colours VALUES (1,'red'),(2,'orange'),(3,'yellow'),(4,'green'),(5,'blue'),(6,'indigo'),(7,'violet');

CREATE TABLE things
(thing VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,colour VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO things VALUES
('tomato','red'),
('cherry','red'),
('heart','red'),
('ferrari','red'),
('chrysanthemum','orange'),
('orange','orange'),
('banana','yellow'),
('lemon','yellow'),
('sunflower','yellow'),
('caterpillar','green'),
('cucumber','green'),
('grass','green'),
('sky','blue'),
('suede shoes','blue'),
('bluebell','blue'),
('indigo bunting','indigo'),
('violets','violet');


SELECT c.colour
     , y.thing 
  FROM colours c 
  JOIN things x 
    ON x.colour = c.colour 
  JOIN things y 
    ON y.colour = x.colour 
   AND y.thing <= x.thing 
 WHERE c.colour_id <=3 
 GROUP 
    BY c.colour,x.thing 
HAVING COUNT(*) <=3 
 ORDER 
    BY colour_id;
+--------+---------------+
| colour | thing         |
+--------+---------------+
| red    | cherry        |
| red    | cherry        |
| red    | cherry        |
| orange | chrysanthemum |
| orange | chrysanthemum |
| yellow | banana        |
| yellow | banana        |
| yellow | banana        |
+--------+---------------+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36937/1